# SASS creating problem while doing npm install on aws server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sass

I am trying to deploy my mern stack project on aws ec2 instance. I am trying to run npm install on client folder and it's giving me

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2020-09-10T17_33_41_380Z-debug.log
```

Comment: @MarkB please check the updated question

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: delete ```package-lock.json``` and try ```npm i``` again

Comment: @HidaytRahman tried to delete and npm i again but the same error persist

Comment: whats the node version?

Comment: @HidaytRahman node version is 12.18

Comment: @VivekModi Try Re-compiling scss file in your local and check if you are getting the same error.